# How to search in this activerecord example?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Two models:

Invoice

```
  :invoice_num        string
  :date               datetime
  .
  .
  :disclaimer_num     integer (foreign key)
```

Disclaimer

```
  :disclaimer_num     integer
  :version            integer
  :body               text
```

For each `disclaimer` there are multiple versions and will be kept in database. This is how I write the search (simplified):

```
scope = Invoice.scoped({ :joins => [:disclaimer] })
scope = scope.scoped :conditions => ["Invoice.invoice_num = ?", "#{params[:num]}"]
scope = scope.scoped :conditions => ["Disclaimer.body LIKE ?", "%#{params[:text]}%"]
```

However, the above search will search again *all* versions of the disclaimer. How can I limit the search to only the *last* disclaimer (i.e. the `version` integer is the maximum).

Please note:

Invoice does not keep the version number. New disclaimers will be added to disclaimer table and keep old versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want only the invoices with the latest version from disclaimer, put a condition on the `disclaimer_num`. And I also suggest creating a helper method in `Disclaimer` to make the code cleaner in your scope.

```
class Disclaimer < ActiveRecord::Base
  def latest
    find(:first, :order => "version DESC")
  end
end

scope = scope.scoped :conditions => { :disclaimer_num => Disclaimer.latest }
```

And I really hope you removed the sql injection prevention code from your scope for brevity.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, the `scope` should be: `scope = scope.scoped :conditions => { :disclaimer_num => Disclaimer.latest.disclaimer_num }`

Comment: Is diclaimer_num your primary key for the disclaimers table? I was assuming it was and that's why I didn't need the .disclaimer_num.

Comment: It is a composite primary key (if not counting default `id` key), i.e. `:declaimer_num` + `:version`

Comment: That would explain it, :disclaimer_num => Disclaimer.latest automatically convert to the record's id and if that isn't the field you want to check, you have to be explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I might just be stored procedure happy, but I think at this point you'd benefit greatly from a stored procedure (or even a view) that did something like this:

CREATE PROCEDURE GetRecentDisclaimer
@BodyFragmentBeingSearched varchar(200)
AS
SELECT MAX(version), disclaimer_num, body
FROM Disclaimer
WHERE
body LIKE @BodyFragmentBeingSearched
GROUP BY disclaimer_num, body

From there, someone's written a blog about how you'd call a stored procedure in Rails and populate ActiveRecord objects, check it out here:

http://nasir.wordpress.com/2007/12/04/stored-procedures-and-rails-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

Add these two conditions (can be done in scope):

```
"ORDER BY disclaimer.disclaimer_num DESC"
"LIMIT 0, 1"
```